# lerna advantage with yarn workspaces, why use lerna at all

Tags: lerna, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to setup a mono repo and came across lerna+yarn.  My problem is, what is the actual advantage I get in using lerna.  I can use yarn workspaces only and have the same functionality.  I came across the following [Are there any advantages to using Lerna with Yarn workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181762/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-lerna-with-yarn-workspaces) but here there is no specific answer as to the specific advantage of using lerna.

Answer (score 1):

as stated [in the yarn workspaces documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/#toc-how-does-it-compare-to-lerna),

> workspaces are the primitives that tools like lerna can use

You might have a project that only needs workspaces as "primitives", and not lerna. Both are tools, but lerna as a higher-level-tool than yarn workspaces helps you organize your monorepo when you are working on open source or in a team:

The install (bootstrap) / build / start-scripts are at the project root:

- meaning one install and package resolution instead of one for each package
- node_modules at the root is 'fat', in sub-projects it's tiny: One place to look for when you resolve package conflicts
- parallel execution of scripts in sub-projects: E.g. starting up both server and frontend development in watch-mode can just be one command
- publishing and versioning is much easier

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a lot of overlap between the two. The big difference is that Lerna handles package management, versioning and deployment.